# my javascript array is coming through as individual characters

Tags: javascript, zapier

I am working with javascript coding in creating a new search in Zapier and need to retrieve an array containing the children of a child of an element - the name of categories.

My initial call and return gives code as seen below in "Return 1"

```
return [results];
```

However, as I said, I need the names in the categories, so I added to my code :

```
for (i=0; i<=2; i++){
    ans[i] = results.projects[0].categories[i].name;
}
return [ans];
```

but now my returned array contains the letter characters as elements. (see Return 2 below)
 What am I missing?

Return 1 :

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Test Project 1",
  "status": {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "development",
    "label": "development"
  },
  ...
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "General",
      "project": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test Global Category 1",
      "project": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": null
      }
    },
    }
  ]
}
```

Return 2:

```
[
  {
    "0": "G",
    "1": "e",
    "2": "n",
    "3": "e",
    "4": "r",
    "5": "a",
    "6": "l"
  },
  {
    "0": "T",
    "1": "e",
    "2": "s",
    "3": "t",
    "4": " ",
    "5": "G",
    "6": "l",
    "7": "o",
    "8": "b",
    "9": "a",
    "10": "l",
    "11": " ",
    "12": "C",
    "13": "a",
    "14": "t",
    "15": "e",
    "16": "g",
    "17": "o",
    "18": "r",
    "19": "y",
    "20": " ",
    "21": "1"
  }]
```

Comment: So you are trying to return an array of category names? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: I don't see anything in your loop that would split the strings into arrays.

Comment: I agree with Barmar, maybe you missed out some code here. It would help if you posted the exact code you're using.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    let projects = {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test Project 1",
      "status": {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "development",
        "label": "development"
      },
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "General",
          "project": {
            "id": 0,
            "name": null
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Test Global Category 1",
          "project": {
            "id": 0,
            "name": null
          }
        },
      ]
    } 
    let names = projects.categories.map((x)=>{
    return (x.name);
    })

    console.log(names)
```

Here we are accessing the categories from a program object and pushing all the names of each category into an array. If you have more than one program then loop through each of the program to get all the names of categories.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re just trying to reach nested JSON data you shouldn’t need to iterate with a for loop.

Set ‘categories’ equal to a variable and then use ‘dot notation’ to access ‘name’.

Something like ‘let categories = res.data.categories’. Then access ‘name’ like this ‘categories.name’.

There probably isn’t a need to use a for loop.